# datatables: how to refresh table when data changes?

Tags: datatables

I use that script to fill datatables:

```
function fillTable(tableid, data, columns) {
    return $(tableid).DataTable({
        data:data,
        "columns": columns
    });
}
```

Where data are aray of objects and that works great.

Then I try to change the data in datatable with new datas:

```
function tableRefresh(dataTable, datas) {
    dataTable.data = datas;
}
```

Problem is: my tables does not display / refresh the data.

I tried with

```
dataTable.draw()
```

Any idea of how to refersh the content of the datatable so it display the current data ?

Comment: are you saying `dataTable = fillTable(tableid, data, columns)` ??

Comment: yes : that's exact !

Comment: And you cannot say `dataTable.data = datas` read the documentation.

Comment: Of course I can ! I do that when filling the table for the first time and that works perfectly